# Find Exception caller and modify to display a value

Tags: java, oop, japplet

Suppose I have 3 TextFields - used for users to input values into (when the program is running):

```
TextField input1 = new JTextField("00");
TextField input2 = new JTextField("00");
TextField input3 = new JTextField("00");
```

When the user inputs values, the program then takes those values and stores them as Integers (for operations later on):

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

  String temp1 = input1.getText();
  String temp2 = input.getText();
  String temp3 = input3.getText();

  int num1=0, num2=0, num3=0;
  if(e.getSource() == storeButton){
      try{
          num1 = Integer.parseInt(tem1);
          num2 = Integer.parseInt(temp2);
          num3 = Integer.parseInt(temp3);
      } 
      catch(NumberFormatException ex){
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Input must be an integer from 0 to 50");
      }
  }
}
```

As the above code shows, when the user clicks the **storeButton** the values in the TextFields are parsed into the specific variables as integers and if any of the TextFields contain an input besides an integer, a message will pop up.

**The question:**

When the exception is called, how do I clear (set to "0") the TextField that does not contain a number? **The TextFields that contain an integer must not be cleared.**
I can do that by using **try** and **catch** for each of the TextFields when parsing as integers but that would mean too much repetition of code (especially when there are many TextFields).

Comment: Pass each input to a method that checks that input. One place for the try/catch, and you know which one has failed. Simple refactoring, and could go further.

Comment: *`NumberFormatException..`*  Why subject the user to that?  Instead offer them a `JSpinner` using a `SpinnerNumberModel` and it will never come up..

Comment: I can't say but it's a requirement in the assignment. I'm aware there are other ways, some which are more efficient, but it's a requirement :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Character.isDigit(). You could make a sub-method that loops through each String and checks it to see if it is a digit.
Alternatively, you could use a regex on the String to check if it is a digit.
This lets you get rid of the try/catch and handle them with if/else.

Comment: The assignment requires use of exception handlers. I implemented matches(regex) with an array of strings (each string containing the specific TextField data). When the exception is called, if statements are used within a for loop where each of the string is compared to regex and if it doesn't match, the associated TextField text is set to "0". Your reply helped with building the idea in my mind, i'll accept it as an answer :)

Comment: Thanks, that was my goal. I think you learn more by giving it a try than looking at a pre-written answer. Now that you've got the answer I'm happy to move this to chat if you'd like to see some examples of how I'd code it.

Comment: That'd be nice. I'm no expert but i'm sure there are much more efficient ways than my implementation. :) And, you're welcome.

Comment: Great, join this room when you get a chance: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139/javachat-fish-and-chips